# How do I update Ruby-interpreters with RVM?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I installed RVM with a few versions of Ruby-interpreters some time ago.
How I can to update it, because new versions are already released?

I found only one way: `rvm install 1.9.2-rc1 && rvm remove 1.9.2-preview1`, but my gems are lost.
Can I update branches time to time? I haven't found any tips in the documentation.

Comment: Can you change the accepted answer because of the rvm upgrade command?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Current rvm version provides an easier way to do this. The 'upgrade' option will migrate gem sets, wrappers and environment files -

```
$ rvm upgrade 1.9.2-p136 1.9.2-p180
```

To find out if there is a more recent stable version of a ruby implementation for you to upgrade to, first get the latest version of RVM and then enumerate the known versions of Ruby.

```
$ rvm get stable
$ rvm list known
```

You can compare this the ruby versions installed on your system

```
$ rvm list rubies
```

Comment: In order to see later Ruby versions, (it seems that first one must) run `rvm get stable`.

Answer (score 85):

Use the `rvm upgrade 1.9.2-preview1 1.9.2-rc1` command or watch this [screencast](http://blog.rubyhead.com/2010/09/01/upgrading-ruby-in-rvm/)

Comment: what will happen to my gemsets of 1.9.2-preview1

Comment: according to `rvm help upgrade`: `Will migrate gemsets, wrappers, aliases
  and environment files.`

Comment: Also, current versions of RVM upgrade in an expected order `rvm upgrade [source ruby] [destination ruby]`.  Wayne fixed that :)

Comment: `rvm upgrade` is the recommended way, so this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: the screencast is a little outdated it would seem, now you run it as: `rvm upgrade from to` instead of the earlier to -> from.

Comment: Also, if you just want to upgrade to the latest patch version, just using the major version works well: `rvm upgrade 1.9.3 1.9.3`

Answer (score 25):

[Edit: rvm has a new command to upgrade-- you likely want to use the answer by andy318]

AFAIK, there is no automatic way to do this at the moment, but something like this enables you to keep your gems:

```
 rvm use 1.9.2-preview1
 rvm gemset export
 rvm install 1.9.2-rc1
 rvm use 1.9.2-rc1
 rvm gemset import
 rvm remove 1.9.2-preview1
```

Now, for automating updates, you would have to detect version changes, that is easy, as you can simply use the return value of `rvm use 1.9.2`. Finding out what the new version is (`1.9.2-rc1`) is unnecessary, as it is aliased as 1.9.2. The trick is to find the latest installed version of 1.9.2. You could do something like this in a cron job:

```
# make sure you source rvm first
rvm update --head
rvm reload
if [ ! rvm use 1.9.2 ]; then
  for ruby_version in `rvm list strings`; do
    # find the latest version of 1.9.2
    case $ruby_version in
      ruby-1.9.2-*) latest192=$ruby_version;;
    esac
  done
  rvm use $latest192
  rvm gemset export 192.gems
  rvm install 1.9.2
  rvm use 1.9.2
  rvm gemset import 192
  rvm remove $latest192
fi
```

Did not try that, but I have similar code in my update script. I also slipped in a `gem update` and other stuff.

Feel free to visit the #rvm IRC channel on Freenode.

Comment: Use rvm upgrade instead, see below.

Answer (score 3):

you can install latest rvm and ruby by :

$ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby

and check all the ruby version with stability

$ rvm list known

can also check details here : http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/

$ rvm install ruby 2.0.0-p247

Use when you want to download specific version or know this is stable.

Answer (score 2):

There's a fantastic RVM GUI called JewelryBox that I use to manage my Ruby versions

http://jewelrybox.unfiniti.com

Comment: After reading this I checked https://rvm.io/ and JewelryBox is stated to be the **official RVM GUI** (OS X users only). This was a real help, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I think that is:

```
rvm all do gemset update
```